Azure App Service mutual ssl filter client certificates
I am hosting application using Azure App Service (windows hosting)
Already have configured the application to require client certificate and that part works fine
When user tries to access application it is given an option to choose certificate from the list of available certificates
What I want is to filter the list of certificates displayed to the user in the browser to not have all the certificates marked for "Client Authentication" usage but only subset of those certificates signed by list of trusted certificates
From what I have read nginx have such configuration parameter ssl_client_certificate containing list of trusted CA certificates which will be sent to clients in this case browsers so they can filter based on that list.
In windows we should be able to control the same by using Client Authentication Issuers (ClientAuthIssuer) store and SendTrustedIssuerList registry value to enable sharing of trusted CA list with browsers which is disabled by default
Wasn't able to found out how it can be configured in Azure App Service. Is it possible to control that certificate store and registry value in Azure App Service?

Based on my understanding of your scenario description, App Service has a list of Trusted Root Certificates which you cannot modify in the multi-tenant variant version of App Service, but you can load your own CA certificate in the Trusted Root Store in an App Service Environment (ASE), which is a single-tenant environment in App Service.
Solution : Use a certificate that is issued by one of the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities in App Service on the remote server.
Ref: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/06/22/Root-CA-on-App-Service-Guide.html

Checkout: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#load-certificate-in-linuxwindows-containers - shows how it's configured.

@AjayKumar thanks for the answer, I am not looking to add new trusted certificate to the server but to share the list of trusted certificates with browser so the list of client certificates displayed to the customer is filtered, containing only those trusted by the server. Still not able to find out how to do that using App Service in any plan, it might be not possible in multi-tenant plan as I am using but still not able to find any guide how to do it in isolated plan as well
